# jQuery AJAX get fields back from PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json, object

The following code sends some data to a PHP file. That PHP file encodes to a JSON object and echoes three variables `error`, `success`, and `action`.

However, neither the success function here, nor the error function appear to be returning that JSON object.

How would one get the values for these three keys back.

```
$.ajax({ 
     type: 'POST',
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     url: ua['url'], 
     data: { sconnect: 'email', email : $('#semail').val(), hack:86 }, 
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (data) {
         alert(data['success']); alert(data['error']); alert(data['action']);
     },
     error: function(data){
         alert(data['success']); alert(data['error']); alert(data['action']);
     }
});
```

Comment: what number is the http request status code?

Comment: firstly, use `console.log()`, not `alert()` for debugging. hit f12 and view the browser network/console tabs. is `$.ajax` ever called? do you see the request in the net tab?